# Export data into excel sheet - drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

Need to export the web page contents into an excel sheet using drupal 6. 
The web page content is coming from a tpl file.
Suggest me a best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a lot of detail about what the content is. If you are using the Views module, you may be able to use the [Views Excel Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) module to export the data to Excel. The [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) module also exports to CSV which can easily be opened in Excel.

Comment: p.s. - You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Matt,contents are coming from web services and i am showing them in a table format and **export that table contents into EXCEL sheet**. I m not using views.